# Call is only returning 1 route when alternatives is 2

Tags: here-api

I am currently trying to figure out why the alternatives param is not working (only getting 1 route in result). The URL I am calling is:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={API_KEY}&mode=car&waypoint0=40.65523%2C-73.95024&waypoint1=40.73189%2C-74.17398&alternatives=2&units=imperial&tollVehicleType=car&return=polyline%2Cactions%2Cinstructions%2Csummary%2CtravelSummary%2CturnByTurnActions%2Celevation%2CrouteHandle1
```

I have seen a few of the answers, however they required an APP CODE which I do not have. When trying to generate an APP CODE it is asking for the bundle id/package name which I do not have (this is running on PHP).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As our Fleet Telematics API will always taking toll cost into consideration during route calculation, it will not always return alternative routes.

Please note definition of "alternatives" parameter from the document at [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html): Maximum number of alternative route options to return. **Can return less or no alternatives. Only returns route alternatives that significantly differ from the best route but are not much more costly.**

If cost calculation is not the main goal of yours, you can always try our Routing API to get the alternatives.

Regarding to app_id/app_code, they are used for the legacy API endpoints, for example https://fleet.api.here.com/. For the current API endpoints, API key should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main goal is too fold: multiple route + toll cost. We currently use tollguru as the main provider and was hoping to switch the main provider to here and have tollguru as backup, but since this isn't feasible we will have to switch that around (I don't mind the backup just showing 1 route).